# Zend spaces when inputting digits

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to know how I can separate numbers or make sure there are spaces between numbers the user enters, e.g. input `0797238189` is converted to `079 723 8189`.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client side when the user enters the numbers or do you want to do this on the server side when the values are posted from the form?

Comment: On the client side please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a javascript library like [Mask](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/).

For a phone number you can try a mask like this `new Mask("### ### ####");`
So for a complete example :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./masks.js"></script>
        <script>
        function init(){
            document.frmExample.reset();
            oPhoneMask = new Mask("### ### ####");
            oPhoneMask.attach(document.frmExample.phone_number);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <form name="frmExample" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
            <b> Phone Number:</b><br />
            <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" /><br />
            Generic: ### ### ####
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying this using a zend element phonenumber downloaded the mask folder added it to my layouts, and did that script in my view, but is failing to run

Answer (score 1):

If you want it on the client side, then you can use jquery like so which will add a space after the user enters a certain number of characters into your text field:

```
$('#myTextFieldId').change(function(){
    if ($(this).length == 3) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ' ');
    } else if ($(this).length == 7) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ' ');
    }
});
```